# How to pass multiple array values of checkbox in PHP to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I wanted to create a selection pages (by using checkboxes) where at the end it will show the result from the selection of all the checkboxes. There are about 5 different categories of checkboxes in my first page (only contains HTML) which is for emotions, time, movements, tools & personalization.

First page: index.php

```
    <div>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
    <label>Select your emotions :</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emotions[]" value="Sadness"> Sadness
    <input type="checkbox" name="emotions[]" value="Anxiety"> Anxiety
    <input type="checkbox" name="emotions[]" value="Anger"> Anger
    <input type="checkbox" name="emotions[]" value="Disgust"> Disgust
    <input type="checkbox" name="emotions[]" value="Fear"> Fear
    <input type="checkbox" name="emotions[]" value="Surprised"> Surprised
    <br>
    <label>Select your time to commit :</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="1"> Less than 1 minute
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="1-3"> 1-3 minutes
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="3-5"> 3-5 minutes
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="5-10"> 5-10 minutes
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="10-15"> 10-15 minutes
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="15-30"> 15-30 minutes
    <br>
    <label>Select how you want to move :</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="movement[]" value="Lying Down"> Lying Down
    <input type="checkbox" name="movement[]" value="Sitting"> Sitting
    <input type="checkbox" name="movement[]" value="Standing"> Standing
    <input type="checkbox" name="movement[]" value="Stretching"> Stretching
    <input type="checkbox" name="movement[]" value="Walking"> Walking
    <input type="checkbox" name="movement[]" value="Work-out"> Work-out
    <br>
    <label>Tools around me :</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tools[]" value="Me"> Me
    <input type="checkbox" name="tools[]" value="Pen & Paper"> Pen & Paper
    <input type="checkbox" name="tools[]" value="Bottle"> Bottle
    <input type="checkbox" name="tools[]" value="Color Pencils"> Color Pencils
    <input type="checkbox" name="tools[]" value="Drinks"> Drinks
    <input type="checkbox" name="tools[]" value="Snacks"> Snacks
    <label>Personalization :</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="personalization[]" value="Favorites"> Favorites
    <input type="checkbox" name="personalization[]" value="New"> New
    <input type="checkbox" name="personalization[]" value="Completed"> Completed
    <input type="checkbox" name="personalization[]" value="Islamic"> Islamic
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

2nd page: process.php

```
<?php
$emotions = (isset($_POST['emotions'])) ? $_POST['emotions'] : array(); ?>
<p><strong>Emotions :</strong>
    <?php
    if (count($emotions) > 0) {
        foreach ($emotions as $emotions) {
            echo $emotions . ' ';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No emotions has been selected";
    }
    ?>
</p> 

<?
$time = (isset($_POST['time'])) ? $_POST['time'] : array(); ?>
<p><strong>Time :</strong>
    <?php
    if (count($time) > 0) {
        foreach ($time as $time) {
            echo $time . ' ';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No time has been selected";
    }
    ?>
</p> 
<?
$movement = (isset($_POST['movement'])) ? $_POST['movement'] : array(); ?>
<p><strong>Movement :</strong>
    <?php
    if (count($movement) > 0) {
        foreach ($movement as $movement) {
            echo $movement . ' ';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No movements has been selected";
    }
    ?>
</p> 

<?
$tools = (isset($_POST['tools'])) ? $_POST['tools'] : array(); ?>
<p><strong>Tools :</strong>
    <?php
    if (count($tools) > 0) {
        foreach ($tools as $tools) {
            echo $tools . ' ';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No tools has been selected";
    }
    ?>
</p> 

<?
$personalization = (isset($_POST['personalization'])) ? $_POST['personalization'] : array(); ?>
<p><strong>Personalization :</strong>
    <?php
    if (count($personalization) > 0) {
        foreach ($personalization as $personalization) {
            echo $personalization . ' ';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No personalization has been selected";
    }
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: So what is your problem... Maybe I'm blind but I can't see a description of it in the post

Comment: Which is the problem? just 1 tip don't use same name in foreach (`foreach ($emotions as $emotion)`)

Comment: The problem is in the title? :D

Comment: Code looks fine, try debugging, check if you are receiving values in 2nd php, if receiving in what format, you will get it then.

Comment: Your title is a rather broad question...it doesn't explain what issue you're having when you try to use the code you've posted. Give us a more specific problem description

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have entered proper path in action attribute of form tag to reach the "process.php" file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Review your foreach.
What you do is :

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
foreach($array as $array){
  // $array is no more an array, but have the first value of the init array : 1
}
```

it's like if you do : $array = $array[0]

you have to do something like :

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
foreach($array as $ar){
  ...
  // code for $ar
  ...
}
```